# Django jsonfields ValidationError: [u'Enter valid JSON'] upon upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: django, django-jsonfield

I'm upgrading django from 1.7 to 1.9 by means of replacing packages, installed in system (Debian 8) via `apt-get` with packages, installed via `pip`.

So, I installed `jsonfield` package from pip instead of apt's good old `python-django-jsonfield` and tried running unittests.

All my jsonfields, defined as `jsonfield.JSONField()`, fail the tests with message:

```
ValidationError: [u'Enter valid JSON']
```

Everything worked fine before. Any ideas, what's changed?

Comment: add a bit of your code that uses JSONField

Comment: @e4c5 Thanks for your interest. I solved the problem and added my findings about jsonfields in Django to the question.

Comment: I think you should post that as an answer. You can of course accept your answer. Then it will be usefull to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Django 1.7 I used `jsonfield 0.9`, but now I installed `jsonfield 1` and there's a significant difference between them. Unfortunately, `jsonfield 0.9` makes use of `simplejson` (`from django.utils import simplejson as json`), which is not available in Django 1.9.

As I'm using Django 1.9 anyways and there's built-in support for `JSONField` in `django.contrib.postgres.fields`, I switched to it. I solved my problems by adding `null=True`, `blank=True` to `JSONField` definition:

```
JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```